PW encryption with jOOQ
I want to encrypt password for my spring web app. I am using jOOQ and Postgre. I pass the variables and using the crypt(?, gen_salt('bf', 12) encryption.
It works in console, but when I am calling it: jOOQ; Bad grammar
private static final String CREATE_USER = """
    INSERT INTO users (title, lastname, firstname, email, password, pin) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, crypt(?, gen_salt('bf', 12), ?)
    """;

I tried to pass it in DSL.field, still bad grammar.
It works in Postgre console.

That is the entirety of the error message? "jOOQ; Bad grammar"
